# Stable Google App Engine Instance Returning 502 Server Error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

After a recent update, an instance of my application deployed via an app engine flex environment has started to return a 502 Server Error virtually all the time. There are rare cases when I can access the live application for a very short window (seconds or minutes).

The application uses NodeJS, express JS router, with a mysql backend. It has been stable for several months and the most recent update included only simple cosmetic changes. The project runs perfectly when tested locally, there are no code issues.

Strange Behavior:
In addition to random, short windows where the application will actually function, there appears to be more evidence the issue is not code related. After the faulty deployment, I started up the last stable instance and migrated all traffic the vm. Despite running for weeks without issue, the old vm also returned the same 502 Server Error.

Possible Source of Issues: My application is not using a Load Balancer.

Comment: The 5XX error codes indicate something happend server-side. You must always check the app's logs to find out more details.

Comment: Why do you think your application isn't using a Load Balancer?  Could you please share your app.yaml?